# How this code makes that hex values?

Tags: java, hex, notepad++, hex-editors

can any one explain me "in details" how this code makes a .cfg file that is like the picture in the left? I wanna change it so that it becomes like the right one?

```
setLastFileInTNM(getTnmInstalledPath(), getLastPath());

private void setLastFileInTNM(String TNMConfigFilePath, String fileTobeSetInTNM) throws Exception {
    //fileTobeSetInTNM  += " ";
    File file = new File(TNMConfigFilePath);
    char[] dt = fileTobeSetInTNM.toCharArray();

    char[] data = readFile(file);

    int offset = 145;
    int length = fileTobeSetInTNM.length();

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 145; i < offset + length; i++) {
        if (j == dt.length) {
            break;
        }
        data[i] = dt[j];
        j++;
    }
    data[offset + length] = (char) 0;//for seprating the rest
    writeToFile(data, file);
    readFile(file);
}
```

This code writes an address in the .cfg file. the picture below is comparing two .cfg file in notepad++. The left one is made by the code above, I want to change the code so that the hex type becomes like the right picture. how should i change the code?
[image]

Comment: where is the picture?

Comment: each row contains 16 bytes (each byte displayed with two hex digits), thus 145 / 16 = 9, the changes should appear in line 10, and they do. Not sure why you have the earlier change in line 6 though. The sides are different, because you the data you write that you get through the fileTobeSetInTNM argument are different.

Comment: the rightest slide is not from the above code, I just want to change the code so that it's hex value becomes like the rightest one from the left one. @Palo

Comment: from what you say it appears to be the other way around. it looks like the data on the right are produced by your code, while the data on the left is some other file you'd like to mimic. The reason to believe this is that your code only writes from location 145, and that happens on the right, while on the left you have additional changes on line 6 and line 29. The file names also suggest that. So you need to give more details of what you do and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text on the right says

`" D : \ M D S   8 3 1 0 . h e x  "`, while the text on the left says

`" D:\MDS 8310.hex 1 0 . h e x    "`.

This suggests that the encoding of the data in the original file is 16-bit per character, leaving every second character as space, and on the left you just copy each character as a byte, thus getting the file name too condensed. If you want to do it in this low level style, just add line

```
data[++i] = 0x20;
```

after line:

```
data[i] = dt[j];
```

and increase the upper bound of the for loop to `offset + length * 2`

I do not see why your file is modified also on the line 29 and on the line 6, but that may depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: yes, line 29 and 6 are because of rest of the code.